# Could not find a suitable mpi compiler (mpicxx or mpic++) whlie using "$ make -f Makefile.shlib auto "

Tags: linux, make

As figure shows, I'm using Linux to install LIGGGHTS, when i type "make -f Makefile.shlib auto", it shows me [auto] Error 2, i tried to set USE_MPI to "OFF", but it did't work, my Question is, how do i using the MPICXX_USR variable? 
Thanks for your felp.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Please do not add images to show error messages. Instead copy&paste the text and use the code button to present the content. Thanks!

Comment: Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).

Comment: I'm sorry for the mistake, thank's for your kind reminder.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an MPI compiler installed, you would set `MPICXX_USR` to the path of its C++ wrapper script (such as `mpic++` or `mpicxx`).  If you don't have MPI installed and don't want to use MPI, you should set `USE_MPI` to the string `OFF`.

The error message says that to set `MPICXX_USR` you should edit the file `MAKE/Makefile.user`.  The `USE_MPI` variable is also settable in this file.

Assuming you have `mpic++` installed and that you want to use MPI to compile this software, determine where `mpic++` is located using

```
command -v mpic++
```

Then set `MPICXX_USR` to this value in `MAKE/Makefile.user`.

The file [`MAKE/Makefile.user_default`](https://github.com/CFDEMproject/LIGGGHTS-PUBLIC/blob/master/src/MAKE/Makefile.user_default) contains the defaults used when compiling LIGGGHTS (this file should probably not be changed, but rather overridden by your own `MAKE/Makefile.user` file).